# How can I pass props (or something similar) to {children} of RootLayout in next js using app router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

*Just for reference, I am creating a shopping cart for an e-commerce website following an old tutorial and updating it to Next.js 13+ as I code.*

In the previous version of the tutorial, the `_app.ts` file was using page routing. The code snippet looked like this:

```
return (
  <>
    <Navbar cart={cart} addToCart={addToCart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />
    <Component cart={cart} addToCart={addToCart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} {...pageProps} />
  </>
);
```

Now, with the new App Routing in Next.js 13+, I have the following code in the `layout.ts` file using app routing:

```
return (
  <html lang="en">
    <body className={inter.className}>
      <Navbar cart={cart} addToCart={addToCart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />
      {children} {/* <-- Alternative code to pass props? */}
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

Are there any other ways to pass props in this new setup, apart from using Redux. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) did the work for me. Redux seemed overkill and there were no other ways to pass props (as per the replies). I wanted to update the states globally so fetching data doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the App Router documents:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

> Passing data between a parent layout and its children is not possible. However, you can fetch the same data in a route more than once, and React will automatically dedupe the requests without affecting performance.

This is an example of how they want you to fetch data in the `page.tsx` file:

```js
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...')
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.
 
  // Recommendation: handle errors
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}
 
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData()
 
  return <main></main>
}
```

Data fetching is mainly based around using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). But you can see a lot more examples of what is doable here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching